# TypeError at /admin/jobs/job/add/ 'tuple' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Actually i am just making a simple blog in Django2.0.2 where i can upload my recent jobs in which i can upload a image and a summary! My Jobs model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)`
```

And i also edited the settings to which the image should be saved:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),

MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
```

the admin.py of the app looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Job

admin.site.register(Job)
```

Please help What should i do to fix this and upload a pic and summary successfully!

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve and what is the problem? Can you please edit the post to clearly point out these two things?

Comment: I made a string Tuple by adding a coma at the end and that was my mistake! Actually i am making a blog in which i have app called jobs where i upload image and the summary of my last job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma from the end of `MEDIA_ROOT`.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

The comma makes it a tuple instead of a string, which causes the error.